# Regex doesn't match the string in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a regex like this:

```
^(.*?(\b\/luxury\/property\b)[^$]*)#contact-broker-msg$
```

That matches url strings like this:

```
https://www.my-website.com/luxury/property/something#contact-broker-msg
```

But when I try to apply this regex in Google Analitics it outputs suspicios results, as if it's not matching urls to my website.

I tested this regex here:

https://regex101.com/r/Jdd4vK/1

And it's shows that example string is a full match for provided regex.

Basically, I just need regex that should match url containg `\/luxury\/property\` and ending with `#contact-broker-msg`.

So, any ideas on whos wrong, me or Google?

Comment: regexes are a pain, and there are many regex "engines".  So when you use a regex in any given client you are at the mercy of whatever regex engine they use.  This means various syntax will work and not work in any given engine, and regex tutorial websites are usually pretty good at pointing these out.  Debugging a regex is universal though.  Start with a small portion that you know works, and build until you find the offending syntax - then google it and find out why that syntax won't work.

Comment: You just need [`/luxury/property/.*#contact-broker-msg$`](https://regex101.com/r/Jdd4vK/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need regex that should match url containg `/luxury/property` and ending with `#contact-broker-msg`.

Google Analytics RE2 patterns do not require full string match, i.e. partial matches are returned, too. So, you do not have to match the whole string with your pattern.

Another point is that you do not have to escape `/` in the RE2 pattern since the regex delimiters are not used.

All you need is

```
/luxury/property/.*#contact-broker-msg$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jdd4vK/2).

**Details**

- `/luxury/property/` - a literal string `/luxury/property/`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `#contact-broker-msg` - a literal string `#contact-broker-msg`
- `$` - end of string.